# Get size of dae node

Tags: scenekit

Suppose I have a collada file which has a box in it and I import the dae file into the scene. Now after importing in the scene I know the dae object is a box. How can I get the dimensions of the box in scenekit after adding it to the scene

If I import the node as a SCNBox i get errors saying that SNCBox is not a subtype of SCNNode.

```
    floorNode = scene.rootNode.childNodeWithName("floor", recursively: false) as SCNBox
    floorNode?.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody.staticBody()
    floorNode?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 2

    let floorGeo: SCNBox  = floorNode.geometry! as SCNBox
```

How do I get the dimensions if SCNNode is the only way to import nodes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Example Swift code on how to use `boundingBox`:

```
var min = shipNode.boundingBox.min
var max = shipNode.boundingBox.max
let w = CGFloat(max.x - min.x)
let h = CGFloat(max.y - min.y)
let l = CGFloat(max.z - min.z)
let boxShape = SCNBox (width: w , height: h , length: l, chamferRadius: 0.0)
let shape = SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: boxShape, options: nil)

shipNode.physicsBody!.physicsShape = SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: boxShape, options: nil)
shipNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody.dynamic()
```

Answer (score 11):

SCNBox is just *helper* subclass of SCNGeometry for box geometry creation. When you import Collada into a scene, you get scene graph of SCNNodes with SCNGeometries, not SCNBox'es or SCNCones etc doesn't matter how they look. If you want to get dimensions of any node you should use  `SCNBoundingVolume` protocol, which is implemented by both SCNNode and SCNGeometry classes:

[func getBoundingBoxMin(_ min: UnsafeMutablePointer,
                       max max: UnsafeMutablePointer) -> Bool](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNBoundingVolume_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/SCNBoundingVolume/getBoundingBoxMin:max:)

With this method you will get bounding box corners.
For box-shaped geometry, dimensions will match bounding box.

Example:

```
var v1 = SCNVector3(x:0, y:0, z:0)
var v2 = SCNVector3(x:0, y:0, z:0)
node.getBoundingBoxMin(&v1, max:&v2)
```

Where *node* is node you want to get bounding box of. 
Results will be in v1 and v2.

**Swift 3**

Using Swift 3 you can simply use `node.boundingBox.min` and `node.boundingBox.max` respectively.

Comment: Hi thanks!. Could you show how to use the getBoundingBox function? I mean I dont understand the meaning of unsafeMutuablePoints. :D

Comment: Updated answer with example. In this case unsafe pointers is just like in C.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks! So Using the bounding box I can check for collision? If I didnt want to use physics for collision detection. Does scenekit has something like intersects.CollisionBox?!?!

Comment: In SceneKit collision detection is done using node's physics body (which can be bounding box, bounding sphere or other geometry). You can use only collision detection, not all physics (physics field etc). Also, you may want to take a look at SCNNode's `hitTest(_:options:)`

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5.4.**

import ARKit

```
extension SCNNode {
    
    var height: CGFloat { CGFloat(self.boundingBox.max.y - self.boundingBox.min.y) }
    var width: CGFloat { CGFloat(self.boundingBox.max.x - self.boundingBox.min.x) }
    var length: CGFloat { CGFloat(self.boundingBox.max.z - self.boundingBox.min.z) }
    
    var halfCGHeight: CGFloat { height / 2.0 }
    var halfHeight: Float { Float(height / 2.0) }
    var halfScaledHeight: Float { halfHeight * self.scale.y  }
}

// Usage:
let node = SCNNode()
node.height
node.width
node.lenght
```